# Does PM.SE have a recommended reading list of PM texts?

Tags: discussion

Does an SE thread exist (community wiki) to collate best practice books, white papers or case studies; possibly with reviews?

If not - I would be interested in contributing to a PM.SE/BoK if it is within the parameters of SE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a Stack Exchange Q&A site, we've found that these compilations don't really fit too well with the model. The best questions tend to be of a narrower focus, such as everyday problems faced in the field of project management.

Some questions can be answered with material that are supported by a book or a third party resource. These are oftentimes the best questions since the answers draw on both personal expert experiences as well as documented case studies or reference material to help back up the claims even further.

But questions asking for little more than a list of books tend to just create more problems than they solve:

1. The list is hard to maintain.
2. It's tough to vote on the best content.
3. The answers require little to no expertise from the community, which can drive away those very same experts we rely on to solve the tough problems.

With that said, you can find some of this on our site from our early days in [this search for "books"](https://pm.stackexchange.com/search?q=books). However, many of these questions -- the ones that are closed -- are not considered good, on-topic questions on our site.

On a final note, I have seen some Stack Exchange sites place names of books in the [Help Center "What topics can I ask about here?"](https://pm.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) page. If people feel strongly that a brief getting started list would be helpful to possibly avoid those questions hitting the main Q&A site, that is something we could possibly discuss here in meta. Hope this helps.

---

I will take a moment to recommend ["Reinventing Communication"](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1472411005), a book written by one of our site's moderators, [Mark Phillips](https://pm.stackexchange.com/users/14/mark-phillips), which features Project Management Stack Exchange as a communication design case study on page 21.  I'm most of the way through this book, and it's made me rethink how I view communication on my team and that sometimes less is more.

Many of our prominent members, such as Mark, will place links to books they've written in their profiles.  See [the top users page](https://pm.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=all) for a list of our top users.

Also, if you wish to bounce around ideas on more books to read, we do have a [chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/380/the-pmse-notice-board). It's mostly quiet, but we do try to encourage more people to participate.

Comment: Fantastic - thank you for the response.

Answer (score 1):

I recently discovered the Mathematics Meta SE which has a BoK Reading List precisely to stop book questions and collate useful texts.

https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18946/learning-roadmap-request-compiling-a-mathematics-stack-exchange-undergraduate